# Removing multiple objects from Redux state array

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a Redux state with the following structure:

```
const initialState = {
  data: [
    'device_groups': [
      {
       'id': '1', 'name': 'group 1',
       'devices': [
         {'id': 11, 'name': 'device 11', 'active': 1}, 
         {'id': 12, 'name': 'device 12', 'active': 1},
         {'id': 13, 'name': 'device 13', 'active': 1}
      ]}, 
      {
       'id': '2', 'name': 'group 2',
       'devices': [
         {'id': 21, 'name': 'device 21', 'active': 1}, 
         {'id': 22, 'name': 'device 22', 'active': 0}
       ]}
    ],
   selectedDevices: [
     {'id': 11, 'name': 'device 11', 'active': 1},
     {'id': 12, 'name': 'device 12', 'active': 1},
     {'id': 21, 'name': 'device 21', 'active': 1},
     {'id': 13, 'name': 'device 13', 'active': 1}
   ]
};
```

In my component when I click on a group, I want to remove all the objects with the same ID as objects in the clicked group from the `selectedDevices` array. In this case objects with IDs 11, 12, 13.

I tried to do it in several ways, but it seems I always remain with the same array. For example I tried this:

```
const handleClickedGroup = (state, action) => {
  const updatedDevices = [...state.data.device_groups[action.groupIndex].devices].slice();
  let updatedSelectedDevices = [...state.selectedDevices].slice();
  let newSelDevices = [];

  for (let i in updatedDevices) {
    const selectedDeviceIndex = findObjectIndex(updatedSelectedDevices, updatedDevices[i], 'id');
    newSelDevices = [
      ...updatedSelectedDevices.slice(0, selectedDeviceIndex),
      ...updatedSelectedDevices.slice(selectedDeviceIndex + 1)
    ];
  }

  return updateObject(state, {selectedDevices: newSelDevices});
}
```

I tried few more things, but nothing worked for me. Is it possible to do that?

**UPDATE**

I think I found a solution:

```
const updatedDevices = [...state.data.device_groups[action.groupIndex].devices].slice();
let updatedSelectedDevices = [...state.selectedDevices].slice();
return updateObject(state, {selectedDevices: updatedSelectedDevices.filter(i => !updatedDevices.some(j => j.id === i.id))});
```

However I'm not sure I'm doing it immutably. Can someone please confirm it?

Comment: Is `data` an array or is it a typo ?

Comment: @Treycos Yes, it is an array.

Comment: Oh well, the last line of your edit was what I was starting to write, nevermind. Happy coding

Comment: The `.slice()` calls are redundant. When you spread the Array, you're creating a new Array. You can either remove the `[...x]` or the `.slice()` call, you only need one.

Comment: @RossAllen Yup, forgot all about it! Added it as one of the attempts to make it work, was afraid I'm now getting a new array and mutating the original. Thanks! :)

Comment: @Treycos Thanks, mate! :)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually this what did the trick for me:

```
const updatedDevices = [...state.data.device_groups[action.groupIndex].devices];
let updatedSelectedDevices = [...state.selectedDevices];
return updateObject(state, {
  selectedDevices: updatedSelectedDevices.filter(i => !updatedDevices.some(j => j.id === i.id))
});
```